# Paper accepted three hours after submission

Tags: peer-review, conference

I have submitted a paper to a conference sponsored by IEEE. After 3 hours, i received an email that said

> your paper has been accepted and recommend to present paper. Your paper will be recommended for publication in IEEE Xplore�. The conference date is after 23 days.

Note: I didn’t receive any reviewer comments on my paper. Only 6 points are written which seems to be general for every paper.

Is it really possible that they have reviewed the paper or did they just accept the paper without review?

Comment: That language ("recommended for inclusion") makes me think this conference is using IEEE conference publishing services, but is not actually sponsored by IEEE. (See [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/104668/11365).)

Comment: It is using the sentence, Your paper will be recommended for publication in IEEE Xplore.

Comment: A lot of red flags here! It was definitely not peer reviewed in any meaningful sense (0% chance). The wording of recommended for publication is odd, and Xplore is the digital library as a whole ( not the name of a proceeding or journal). If it is just a non-archival social event conference, and if that is a thing that happens in your field, fine - but it certainly doesn't sound like any serious academic research venue for real papers.

Comment: Which field and conference is it, this may allow people in your field to have a closer look.

Comment: It is related to EE but has wide reseach topics including signal processing, etc.

Comment: @BrianH what is non archival social event conference.

Comment: @user91272 Basically a dinner party.

Answer (score 7):

It's impossible that the paper was reviewed (at least by a human). 3 hours is way too short. Weeks is a much better order of magnitude estimate for the time required to review papers.

It sounds like you're dealing with a predatory conference. I would approach with care. Check if the conference's scientific committee are actually established researchers in the field, check the keynote speakers to see if other established researchers are intending to attend, check if the conference has been held before and if so, how those conferences went.

Answer (score 3):

It definitely is abnormal, although reviewers usually spend quite little time in practice. I highly suspect this is a conference for MONEY. You'd better withdraw your paper.

There are several (at least some) serious conferences in almost every field. I do not mean the conferences are large or their papers have very high impact factors (but usually they do). I mean they all have high reputation. A direct way to find such conferences is to see who submit their papers to and who attend the conferences. My suggestion is only to submit to these conferences, for your own reputation.

---

It seems that the conference is 'related to EE but has wide research topics including signal processing'. I may assume your paper is about signal processing. For signal processing, there are a bunch of serious conferences including: ICASSP, GlobalSIP, Allerton, Asilomar, etc. You may also consider some communications conferences which also cover signal processing topics, such as ICC, GlobalCom, WCNC. If your research lies in the theoretic part, there are information theory conferences like ISIT, CISS, ITW.

Comment: But it is sponsored by ieee. So it does not mean quality.?

Comment: Not really. The best way is to check who are the chairs, who serves as TPC members, past papers, etc. @user91272